# Text Alignment in CGRect using PDFKit - Swift 5 - Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to center text in a CGrect inside a PDF. I can generate the PDF and draw rects, but ive been looking for a method to draw certain text into certain rects, as the text is filled in by the user, i cant get it to dynamically stay centered. I feel ive run myself down a path and cant find a way back out. Can anyone shed any light or even suggest a fix?

This method produces an error for me

> Cannot convert value of type 'CGRect' to expected argument type 'CGFloat'

Heres an example:

```
func addActNumber(pageRect: CGRect) -> CGFloat {

        let titleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .bold)

        let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: titleFont]
        let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string:"Act \(actNumber)", attributes: titleAttributes)

        let ActNumberStringSize = attributedTitle.size()
        
        let ActNumberRect = CGRect (x: 10 , y: 35, width: 191.6, height: 25 )

        let titleStringRect = CGRect(x:  (ActNumberRect - ActNumberStringSize.width) / 2.0 , y: 35, width: 191.6 ,
                                     height: 25)
      

        attributedTitle.draw(in: titleStringRect)
        

        return titleStringRect.origin.y + titleStringRect.size.height
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the NSMutableParagraphStyle() for your text alignment in a rectangle.
For example:

```
func alignText(value:String, x: Int, y: Int, width:Int, height: Int, alignment: NSTextAlignment, textFont: UIFont){
      let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
      paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment
      let attributes = [    NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
                            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle  ]
      let textRect = CGRect(x: x, 
                            y: y, 
                            width: width,
                            height: height)
      value.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: attributes)
}
```

and run the function with:

```
alignText(value: "Your Text", x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20, alignment: .right, textFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .bold))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Does exactly what the question asks.